# Allowing Pinch to Zoom with jQuery.Wipetouch

Tags: jquery, ipad, zooming, gestures

I'm using the jQuery.Wipetouch plugin to allow swiping gestures to navigate a slideshow.

However, the iPad's native pinch-to-zoom functionality is now broken, because any swiping gestures (apparently including pinch/zoom) are being captured by the bound element.

Is there any way I can enable pinch-to-zoom while maintaining my new swipe gestures? Is there maybe a multitouch event I can listen for to temporarily disable swipe bindings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem. The plugin has a property called 'preventDefault' which defaults to TRUE. This setting disables default event functionality such as pinch-to-zoom.

Setting preventDefault to false fixes the issues with jQuery.Wipetouch not recognizing my pinch-to-zoom gestures.

Comment: preventDefault is not plugin feature, it's a inbuilt function in the browser enabled by javascript. So, its a javascript function.

Comment: Thanks Mirage. I meant that the plugin has a property preventDefault, which uses the underlying JavaScript function.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to reconsidering to change the swipe plugin itself.

You can consider the [touchSwipe](http://labs.skinkers.com/touchSwipe/demo/index.html) plugin which provides you with a [pinch](http://labs.skinkers.com/touchSwipe/demo/Pinch.html) event, as well as an option `excludedElements` which should do the trick that @RobGibbons menitioned.

And apparently according to [plugin site](http://labs.skinkers.com/touchSwipe/demo/index.html) it has support for ipad as well as iphone.

Also as a plus, it is open source([Github](https://github.com/mattbryson/TouchSwipe-Jquery-Plugin))